# Need help converting &quot; to ' when using .val()

Tags: jquery, html, json, regex

I am using jquery to get the value of a hidden input. The hidden input contains a data-trix-attachment attribute with JSON object. The problem is that jquery replaced the quotes with `&quot;` . I am not sure why.

I have looked around for a solution, and can't seem to find one.

I tried doing a regex to replace the `&quot;` with **'** but that didn't work either. (Below is an example)

Can anyone please help me solve this. Below is the code I tried using.

```
    var new1 = $("#trix-input-1").attr("value");
   var e_encoded = new1.replace(/"/g, "&quot;");
```

**HTML Code**

```
<a contenteditable="false" href="http://localhost/gu/attachments/2015-11-161447695275991-Screen Shot 2015-11-16 at 11.36.45 AM.png" data-trix-attachment="{"contentType":"image/png","filename":"Screen Shot 2015-11-16 at 11.36.45 AM.png","filesize":9291,"height":77,"href":"http://localhost/gu/attachments/2015-11-161447695275991-Screen Shot 2015-11-16 at 11.36.45 AM.png","url":"http://localhost/gu/attachments/2015-11-161447695275991-Screen Shot 2015-11-16 at 11.36.45 AM.png","width":305}" data-trix-content-type="image/png" data-trix-id="38">
```

**jQuery Response**

```
<a data-trix-content-type=&quot;image/png&quot; data-trix-attachment=&quot;{&quot;contentType&quot;:&quot;image/png&quot;,&quot;filename&quot;:&quot;Screen Shot 2015-11-16 at 11.36.45 AM.png&quot;,&quot;filesize&quot;:9291,&quot;height&quot;:77,&quot;href&quot;:&quot;http://localhost/gu/attachments/2015-11-161447695275991-Screen Shot 2015-11-16 at 11.36.45 AM.png&quot;,&quot;url&quot;:&quot;http://localhost/gu/attachments/2015-11-161447695275991-Screen Shot 2015-11-16 at 11.36.45 AM.png&quot;,&quot;width&quot;:305}&quot; href=&quot;http://localhost/gu/attachments/2015-11-161447695275991-Screen Shot 2015-11-16 at 11.36.45 AM.png&quot;><figure class=&quot;attachment attachment-preview png&quot;><img src=&quot;http://localhost/gu/attachments/2015-11-161447695275991-Screen Shot 2015-11-16 at 11.36.45 AM.png&quot; height=&quot;77&quot; width=&quot;305&quot;><figcaption class=&quot;caption&quot;>Screen Shot 2015-11-16 at 11.36.45 AM.png <span class=&quot;size&quot;>9.07 KB</span></figcaption></figure></a>
```

**jQuery Code**

```
   var new1 = $("#trix-input-1").val();
```

Comment: Look at the color coding of `data-trix-attachment`, you need to have the entire value be a string, replace the outer `"` with `'` and that will fix your problem. You will not need to do the `&quot;` conversion.

Comment: `"#trix-input-1"` not appear at `html` at Question ?

Comment: Escaping quotes help protect against XSS. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting#Preventative_measures for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Wrong syntax for `replace`, it's `replace(oldStr, newStr)` not the other way round. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

So this:

```
var e_encoded = new1.replace(/"/g, "&quot;");
```

should be:

```
var e_encoded = new1.replace(/&quot;/g, "'");
```

You example works fine:

```js
console.log('<a data-trix-content-type=&quot;image/png&quot; data-trix-attachment=&quot;{&quot;contentType&quot;:&quot;image/png&quot;,&quot;filename&quot;:&quot;Screen Shot 2015-11-16 at 11.36.45 AM.png&quot;,&quot;filesize&quot;:9291,&quot;height&quot;:77,&quot;href&quot;:&quot;http://localhost/gu/attachments/2015-11-161447695275991-Screen Shot 2015-11-16 at 11.36.45 AM.png&quot;,&quot;url&quot;:&quot;http://localhost/gu/attachments/2015-11-161447695275991-Screen Shot 2015-11-16 at 11.36.45 AM.png&quot;,&quot;width&quot;:305}&quot; href=&quot;http://localhost/gu/attachments/2015-11-161447695275991-Screen Shot 2015-11-16 at 11.36.45 AM.png&quot;><figure class=&quot;attachment attachment-preview png&quot;><img src=&quot;http://localhost/gu/attachments/2015-11-161447695275991-Screen Shot 2015-11-16 at 11.36.45 AM.png&quot; height=&quot;77&quot; width=&quot;305&quot;><figcaption class=&quot;caption&quot;>Screen Shot 2015-11-16 at 11.36.45 AM.png <span class=&quot;size&quot;>9.07 KB</span></figcaption></figure></a>'.replace(/&quot;/g, "'"))
```

---

With document.write instead of console output:

```js
document.write('<a data-trix-content-type=&quot;image/png&quot; data-trix-attachment=&quot;{&quot;contentType&quot;:&quot;image/png&quot;,&quot;filename&quot;:&quot;Screen Shot 2015-11-16 at 11.36.45 AM.png&quot;,&quot;filesize&quot;:9291,&quot;height&quot;:77,&quot;href&quot;:&quot;http://localhost/gu/attachments/2015-11-161447695275991-Screen Shot 2015-11-16 at 11.36.45 AM.png&quot;,&quot;url&quot;:&quot;http://localhost/gu/attachments/2015-11-161447695275991-Screen Shot 2015-11-16 at 11.36.45 AM.png&quot;,&quot;width&quot;:305}&quot; href=&quot;http://localhost/gu/attachments/2015-11-161447695275991-Screen Shot 2015-11-16 at 11.36.45 AM.png&quot;><figure class=&quot;attachment attachment-preview png&quot;><img src=&quot;http://localhost/gu/attachments/2015-11-161447695275991-Screen Shot 2015-11-16 at 11.36.45 AM.png&quot; height=&quot;77&quot; width=&quot;305&quot;><figcaption class=&quot;caption&quot;>Screen Shot 2015-11-16 at 11.36.45 AM.png <span class=&quot;size&quot;>9.07 KB</span></figcaption></figure></a>'.replace(/&quot;/g, "'"))
```

Comment: The OP shouldn't be dealing with the `&quot;` at all, they just need to correctly add values into their attribute.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Yup, I've upvoted your comment when you wrote it and didn't want to repeat it. Just gave a direct answer to OPs question about replacing, but I agree the code needs fixing.